# Safari doesn't work with my TCP server

Tags: c, macos, tcp

I made a TCP server that responds with "Hello world!" to every request, and when I go to 127.0.0.1:1999 on Chrome, it shows "Hello world!", but the same on Safari (OSX Capitan) shows "Safari can't open the page because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection."

When I tried the C server example [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hello_world/Web_server#C), I see the same problem: it works with Chrome but not Safari. HOWEVER, the node.js example that does the same thing works with both. What gives?

What can be done with a C TCP server to make Safari happy? I'm less concerned with supporting every browser than I am with making sure I'm not doing something wrong.

Comment: There's a really great tool for Windows called [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) and a similar Mac tool called [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) that allow you to inspect HTTP request/response between browser and server. When there's a protocol error, these tools will often flag the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the C code sample you referenced, I suspect you need a `Content-Length` header in the response.

And if I counted the characters right, it's 240.

```
char response[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n"
"Content-Length: 240"
"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Bye-bye baby bye-bye</title>"
"<style>body { background-color: #111 }"
"h1 { font-size:4cm; text-align: center; color: black;"
" text-shadow: 0 0 2mm red}</style></head>"
"<body><h1>Goodbye, world!</h1></body></html>\r\n";
```

Some of those other implementations on that page for other languages **are just plain wrong** and aren't sending back HTTP 1.1 correctly.

I can give a better answer if you share **your** code.

Comment: It turns out it was not content length, but the other headers. FWIW, my code is here: https://github.com/ys1382/unladen